# Are NSString and NSData the only types I can insert into KeyChain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

You can convert an integer to `NSString` or an array to `NSData` and insert them into the **iOS KeyChain**.

My question is: Is that it? Or is there a direct way to insert a double, float or a boolean?

Comment: I don't think so. But why would you need/care about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store primitive types in form of `NSNumber` and save them to keychain. It has methods like: `numberWithBool:`, `numberWithInteger:`, `numberWithFloat:`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29369667/5381663) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868748/5381663) are examples of storing BOOL in keychain.